# Getting resources with python phantomJS

Tags: python, phantomjs

I am trying to find a way to get all the resources loaded by a page using Python with PhantomJS. Note that some resources may be loaded by scripts, etc. Is there a way to do this? Thanks for all help in advance!

My current code is:

```
    self.driver.get("about:blank")

    js = '''
    console.log('hello world')
    var page = this;
    var urls = Array();
page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
    urls.push(request.url)
};
page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
    urls.push(request.url)
};
return urls
    '''
    result = self.driver.execute_script(js)
    self.driver.get(url_to_open)
    time.sleep(2)
    print(result)
```